# Область видимости (С++)

Tags: c, c++

Я хочу объявить переменную, у которой область - видимости один файл. В языке С это легко решить, используя ключевое слово static. Как сделать подобное на языке С++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В С++ данный вопрос решается с помощью безымянного пространства имен. Поясню на примере.

```
// C код
static int someVar = 0;
static char * ptr = NULL;

// С++ код
namespace {
    int someVar = 0;
    char * ptr = NULL;
}
```

Поскольку пространство имен не имеет имени, его нельзя определить в другом файле исходного кода, а следовательно и обратиться к переменным, объявленным внутри него.